# How do I transform this JSON object into smaller files using bash?

Tags: json, bash, shell

The input JSON file which will be provided to the BASH script is the following:

```
{
    "array": [
        {
            "field1": "value1",
            "field2": "value2", 
            "field3": "value3",
            "field4": "value4",
            "field5": "value5"
        },
        {
            "field1": "value6",
            "field2": "value7", 
            "field3": "value8",
            "field4": "value9",
            "field5": "value10"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to break this up into separate json files like using BASH.
File1 Name: file1.json

```
{
   "field1": "value1",
   "field2": "value2", 
   "field3": "value3",
   "field4": "value4",
   "field5": "value5"
}
```

File2 Name: file2.json

```
{
   "field1": "value6",
   "field2": "value7", 
   "field3": "value8",
   "field4": "value9",
   "field5": "value10"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer to "how do I...JSON...bash" is the [`jq` command](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). While there are probably a number of ways of tackling this, you could do something like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<$(jq '.array|length' data.json); i++ )); do
  jq ".array[$i]" data.json > file$((i+1)).json
done
```

This produces:

```
$ ls -l file*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 113 Feb 17 21:43 file1.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 114 Feb 17 21:43 file2.json
```

Or you can use the [`csplit` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) to split the output:

```
jq '.array[]' data.json | csplit -z -f file -b '%02d.json' - '/^{$/' '{*}'
```

Given your sample input, this produces two files:

```
$ ls -l file*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 113 Feb 17 21:44 file00.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 114 Feb 17 21:44 file01.json
```

Comment: How would this script be modified if the input json were to become something like

```
{
    "key" : {
      "array": [
        {
            "field1": "value1",
            "field2": "value2", 
            "field3": "value3",
            "field4": "value4",
            "field5": "value5"
        },
        {
            "field1": "value6",
            "field2": "value7", 
            "field3": "value8",
            "field4": "value9",
            "field5": "value10"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a Bash script. With the JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) you can do this with just 1 call:

```
$ xidel -s "input.json" -e '
  for $x at $i in $json/array?* return
  file:write(x"file{$i}.json",$x,{"method":"json","indent":true()})
'
```

This yields *'file1.json'* and *'file2.json'*.

Comment: How would this script be modified if the input json were to become something like ``` { "key" : { "array": [ { "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2", "field3": "value3", "field4": "value4", "field5": "value5" }, { "field1": "value6", "field2": "value7", "field3": "value8", "field4": "value9", "field5": "value10" } ] } } ```

Comment: @Shaurya `$json/key/array?*`. Btw, this is not a script, but a command, or rather an extraction-query.